# Return epilogue after test executed in cloud

Tags: selenium, mocha.js, webdriver-io, browserstack

Hi I have a question about reporters output using browserstack. When I start to run test's in cloud reporter output stopped showing epilogue, can I return it somehow?
using spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do this by commenting this line:

```
if (!this.printEpilogue) {
                return;
```

In basereporter.js